# Appium .getPageSources xml encoding

Tags: android, xml, encoding, appium

If I try to get **driver.getPageSource()** in Android Appium, it gives me XML with bad encoding like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
<android.widget.TextView 
index="1" 
text="Florbal - mu?i" 
class="android.widget.TextView"
...
bounds="[68,655][712,696]"
resource-id="my.app.test:id/sport_name"
instance="9" />
```

But text should be **"Florbal - muži"**

I can see right encoding in UI Automator Viewer. And its not caused by Ëclipse console encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its newly reported Appium bug: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4611